# QNetworkAccessManager detect system proxy

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to detect the system default proxy in my Qt app, so that if a default proxy is defined it should be used in `QWebView`s and for `QNetworkAccessManager`.

This is what I got so far:

```
QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(true);
nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

QUrl url("http://url.com/");
QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));

QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)), reply, SLOT(ignoreSslErrors()));
```

It seems to work for my `QWebView`s but is it really using the proxy in my `QNetworkAccessManager`?

Comment: Why don't you test it with an invalid system proxy? Your calls over `QNetworkAccessManager` will fail then.